# Употребление слов «последний» и «крайний»

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов

Слова "последний" и "крайний": в каких случаях правильно употреблять первое слово, а в каких — второе?

Answer (score 5):

Вообще, крайний - это ограниченный в пространстве, а последний - во времени. *Последний защитник* - это защитник оставшийся один, за ним никого нет. *Крайний защитник* - это спортивный термин, обозначающий игрока обороны, действующего по краю.

Однако, у представителей опасных для жизни и здоровья профессий и увлечений (сапёры, пожарные, парашютисты, спортсмены-экстремалы) появилась тенденция не называть опасное мероприятие *последним*, только *крайним*. Связано это суеверие с тем, что под последним можно понимать как последний из уже сделанных, так и последний в жизни. Представители этих профессий стали использовать слово *крайний*. Сейчас "крайний* потихоньку распространяется и по другим сферам, выходя за рамки профессионального жаргона. В целом, если вы не общаетесь с экстремалами, то рекомендации из первого абзаца будет достаточно, в противном случае, там действуют скорее рекомендации этикета, а не лингвистики.

Крайним ещё называют того на кого сваливают всех собак (*сделать крайним*), но это значения оставим за рамками обсуждения, так как последним его не назовут точно.

Answer (score 2):

Последний - в ряду, крайний - в шеренге.
Последний - если один, крйаних обычно больше, как минимум два.

А вообще подобные вопросы обычно связаны с одним профессиональным предрассудком, что последнего раза не бывает. См. здесь.
http://www.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_6_krainij/